# permission error when installing gem from terminal

Tags: terminal, rubygems

I have been trying to install zsteg with the `gem install` command, but i get this error, even as a super-user:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

I have tried `sudo gem install zsteg`, `sudo -s` then `gem install zsteg` and just `gem install zsteg`, but none work. What should I do?

edit: I am using macOSX Mojave and I have ruby

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled rake and zsteg and it worked for me.

```
 1. make sure you have ruby-dev 
 2. update --system
 3. sudo gem install rake
 4. sudo gem install zsteg
```

good luck!

Comment: I use macOSX which doesn't have access to apt-get. Also, brew doesn't have ruby-full

Comment: brew install ruby

Answer (score 0):

So I worked it out. I changed the install directory to /usr/local/bin using this:

```
gem install zsteg -n /usr/local/bin
```